# How do I run a .py script?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, automation

I just started learning Python last week to automate some stuff I do (thanks to automatetheboringstuff.com). Assume I know nothing about programming. The only thing I know is HTML and CSS.

I created a simple automation workflow already and I want to improve not the code (maybe in the future because it's not yet finished) but how I can maintain my setup/program on two laptops -- Both Mac OS running on High Sierra.

I have a .py file that contains my automated workflow. I don't know where to place it. It currently resides in my Dropbox so i can use it on laptop1 and laptop2.

I also created a virtualenv for each machine and did the requirements.txt thing as well (just to prep for the future). The directory is on both username/python/project_name.

I read in some posts that these files and other resources can exist anywhere whether inside each virtualenv or not. And that it's just a preference. I also read that the virtualenv itself isn't recommended to be placed inside apps like Dropbox (that's why i separated it on each laptop).

I switch between both laptops frequently. The environment which contains the packages doesn't really concern me that much when switching. It's the other files that is bothering me. For example,  there's an image I need, this has to be available on both laptops so my solution to this is to have a Resources folder inside Dropbox as well. It currently looks like this:

- Dropbox

  - Projects

    - Project 1 files (images, etc.)
    - Project 2 files (images, etc.)
  - Workflows (this would contain my completed .py files)

I read some stuff about the virtualenvwrapper, but haven't looked at it yet. Maybe in the future when i do have more projects to manage. Because right now, it's just this one.

Lastly, I noticed that every time i open up Terminal and activate my virtualenv, the file directory is in Users/username

How can i set it to default to Dropbox/Projects/project_name? I always have to set it using the chdir(). That way, when i do have multiple projects (and virtualenv) i don't have to worry about where the files load/ save.

Finally, how do I run the .py script? If i open the IDLE, open the .py file there, and use f5, it runs properly. But as far as I know, that doesn't look into the virtualenv i setup. Is that correct?

I tried right-clicking, then Open With > Python Launcher the .py file. and i'm getting an error saying there are no modules found. It seems it's not loading the right virtualenv. So there must be something wrong with the file i made.

Then I read about the #! you place at the beginning of the .py files but i don't understand it. Can someone explain that further? Is that why my file isn't loading properly?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Suggestion: Use Github (or similar service) rather than Dropbox for code. Then you can track changes easier (and undo bad changes)

Comment: I'll take a look. I'm new to this, so I really don't know how all those work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run .py scripts from the command line using:

```
python test.py
```

That tells terminal to run test.py in the python interpreter and send the output to your terminal, just like when you run it in the IDLE. If your .py script is not in your current directory and you don't want to change directories, you can access it using it's absolute path:

```
python /Users/username/Dropbox/Workflows/test.py
```

As long as you have already activated your virtualenv, it should run your script using only the libraries you have added to your virtualenv. Also, once your virtualenv is activated, you can move around directories using "cd" and it will bring your virtualenv with you.

Comment: Awesome. Finally got it to run. Is it good practice to include the os.chdir inside the .py file? If not, is there a way to set the default working directory per virtualenv?

Comment: You have a unique situation. Personally, I've never used os.chdir(). I think your safest option is to activate your virtualenv and then manually navigate to your dropbox directory to work. Do you know how to navigate directories in terminal? If you don't, you should. Most coders can do everything they need to do through terminal without a mouse. Here is a short video on that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AO0jzD1hpXc.

Comment: Thanks for the vid. Yes, i do. That's what i've been doing when i try to test my file. i guess i'm just trying to look for a more 'lazy' way of doing that without having to cd everytime. Thanks for the help!!